# Storing encrypted PrivateKey's to Java Keystores

Tags: bouncycastle, x509certificate

Java Keystores (e.g. JKS, PKCS) allow [saving](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20java.security.cert.Certificate[]))  private keys (interface
[Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html)) and
certificate chains.  However a RSA KeyPair's private key which is encrypted
(e.g.  [EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java) in bouncycastle or in [javax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.html)) does not implement
Key interface.

What is the correct way to store encrypted private keys in a keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have an `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`, you should be able to use that directly when creating the keystore entry. Java stores the PrivateKey in the KeyStore as `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` format.

You need to use this method in the `KeyStore.setKeyEntry(String alias, byte[] key, Certificate[] chain)`. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry-java.lang.String-byte:A-java.security.cert.Certificate:A-).

The other `setKeyEntry` method takes in an addtional argument, which is the password, which the Java will construct the `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` itself with the password provided.

Note: Only if the `Key Protection Algorithm` is supported by Java, it will import the private key, or else it will complain. If it does complain, you can look at other option of decrypting the encrypted private key yourself, and using the other `setKeyEntry()` method.